# Error occured while using Chewie video player package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, video-player

I'm using Chewie video package in my flutter app. Whenever a video url is loaded and ready to play, I get the following exception:

`Error: Bad state: Future already completed dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 288:49  throw_ dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 35:79                                     complete packages/video_player/video_player.dart 406:5                                 initialize dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn> dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                          runUnary dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                    handleValue dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 784:44                                    handleValueCallback dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 813:13                                    _propagateToListeners dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 584:5                                     [_completeWithValue] dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 657:7                                     callback dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 177:15           <fn>`

This is how I'm initializing the controllers for the video player:

```
late List<VideoPlayerController> _videoControllers;
  late List<ChewieController> _chewieControllers;
  bool isInitialized = false;

  final List<String> urls = [
    "https://pinchom.s3.amazonaws.com/hvMCF-VID-20230109-WA0009.mp4",
    
    'https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-clouds-and-blue-sky-2408-large.mp4',
    'https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-different-types-of-fresh-fruit-in-presentation-video-42941-large.mp4',
    
    'https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-waterfall-in-forest-2213-large.mp4',
    'https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-close-up-view-of-a-rotating-vinyl-record-42922-large.mp4',
    'https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-going-down-a-curved-highway-down-a-mountain-41576-large.mp4',
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _videoControllers = List<VideoPlayerController>.generate(
      urls.length,
      (index) => VideoPlayerController.network(urls[index]),
    );
    _chewieControllers = List<ChewieController>.generate(
      urls.length,
      (index) => ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: _videoControllers[index],
        looping: true,
        showOptions: true,
      ),
    );

    for (var controller in _videoControllers) {
      // setState(() {
        
      // });
      controller.initialize();
        isInitialized = true;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    for (var controller in _videoControllers) {
      controller.dispose();
    }
    for (var chewieController in _chewieControllers) {
      chewieController.dispose();
    }
  }
```

I even tried downgrading the chewie package in case that was the issue, still the error persists.